# HMENU with graphics

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In a TYPO3 site, I have a list of sibling pages. Each page has some images in the "media" field. Im trying to make a navigation to go to the previos/next sibling. So far I have this:

```
# Append Sitenavi for projects
[PIDupinRootline = 43]

page.10.marks.MAIN.20 = HMENU
page.10.marks.MAIN.20{

    special = browse
    special{
        items = next|prev
    }

    1 = TMENU
    1{
        NO = 1
    }
}
[global]
```

But instead of using the page title, id like to use the first image from the "files" field. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to get other fields:

```
page.10.marks.MAIN.20 = HMENU
page.10.marks.MAIN.20 {
  special = browse
  special {
    items = prev | next
  }

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO.stdWrap.field = subtitle // title
  }
}
```

Now if your change `subtitle // title` to `image` and add `NO.stdWrap.wrap = <img src"|" />`, then it should work.